# hadoop hdfs client in C

Tags: c, hadoop, hdfs

The question is pertaining to the design and implementation of hdfs client in C. The libhdfs page http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/libhdfs.html mentions that the client uses a JNI interface. Can anyone explain why is the C client using JNI. All the client needs to do is call a remote method in the java program running on the datanode and namenode, which it can do by serializing the method invocation in the manner datanode expects it to be. Using JNI for something so trivial is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

HDFS is completely implemented in Java and uses several features of the Java language and API to make performance good and easy to program. The Hadoop RPC protocol is pretty simple to use as it can be [here](http://www.supermind.org/blog/520) . The simplicity comes from the fact that Hadoop uses the [`Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)
class to intercept the calls and together with the `Writable` interface to serialize the remote procedures call to the server side; which on its turn unpack and does the call.  So the protocol is somewhat dependent on Java.

On the other hand, developing the C biding using JNI makes it easier and  faster to implement and reuses the Java code. And less error prone since you do not have to handle things such as endianess or mimic the Java behavior.

There was a movement to use [Apache Avro](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/) which would make it easier to bind with other languages. So far it seems that is on hold.